# How to modify specific Value on Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, arraylist

I am currently adding quantity update on an app, so basically the the JSON file that currently being streamed need to have their specific value reduced

```
[
  {
    "tipe":"Coffee",
    "image":"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ90z0I0MAspI4vILXQ_iF1IikV8zQTyiWj1eC6Q6OB8w&s",
    "menus": [
      {
        "drink": "Flavored Latte",
        "price": 16000,
        "url": "https://images.media-allrecipes.com/userphotos/776874.jpg",
        "qty": 10
      },
      {
        "drink": "Cappuccino",
        "price": 15000,
        "url": "https://www.thespruceeats.com/thmb/SyX_yUyCFOtuqWC2QFrM25JTmsA=/4413x2942/filters:fill(auto,1)/how-to-make-cappuccinos-766116-hero-01-a754d567739b4ee0b209305138ecb996.jpg",
        "qty": 10
      }
]
```

the file currently being read within main activity

```
    private List<TypeModel> getTypeData() {
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.menu);
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        try{
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));
            int n;
            while(( n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0,n);
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {

        }

        String jsonStr = writer.toString();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        TypeModel[] typeModels =  gson.fromJson(jsonStr, TypeModel[].class);
        List<TypeModel> reList = Arrays.asList(typeModels);

        return  meList;

    }
```

the value that need to be changed are the one in qty based on option being choose when the order are completed which it need to be happen on orderf.activity

orderf.activity

```
public class PlaceYourOrderActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private EditText inputName, inputTable;
    private RecyclerView cartItemsRecyclerView;
    private TextView tvSubtotalAmount, tvTotalAmount, buttonPlaceYourOrder, serial;
    private PlaceYourOrderAdapter placeYourOrderAdapter;
    
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_place_your_order);

        TypeModel typeModel = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("TypeModel");
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle(typeModel.getName());
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        inputName = findViewById(R.id.inputName);
        inputTable = findViewById(R.id.inputTable);
        serial = findViewById(R.id.Serial);
        tvSubtotalAmount = findViewById(R.id.tvSubtotalAmount);
        tvTotalAmount = findViewById(R.id.tvTotalAmount);
        buttonPlaceYourOrder = findViewById(R.id.buttonPlaceYourOrder);

        cartItemsRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.cartItemsRecyclerView);

        buttonPlaceYourOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onPlaceOrderButtonClick(typeModel);
            }
        });

        initRecyclerView(typeModel);
        calculateTotalAmount(typeModel);
        serialview();

    }
private void serialview(){
    int digit = 8;
    int max = (int) Math.pow(10,(digit)) - 1;
    int min = (int) Math.pow(10, digit-1);
    int range = max-min;
    Random r = new Random();
    int x = r.nextInt(range);
    int serialview = x+min;
    serial.setText(Integer.toString(serialview));

}

    private void calculateTotalAmount(TypeModel typeModel) {
        float subTotalAmount = 0f;

        for(Menu m : typeModel.getMenus()) {
            subTotalAmount += m.getPrice() * m.getTotalInCart();
        }

        tvSubtotalAmount.setText("Rp"+String.format("%.2f", subTotalAmount));
        tvTotalAmount.setText("Rp"+String.format("%.2f", subTotalAmount));
    }

    private void onPlaceOrderButtonClick(TypeModel typeModel) {
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(inputName.getText().toString())) {
            inputName.setError("Please enter name ");
            return;
        }
        //start success activity.
        Intent i = new Intent(PlaceYourOrderActivity.this, OrderSucceessActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("TypeModel", typeModel);
        startActivityForResult(i, 1000);
    }

    private void initRecyclerView(TypeModel typeModel) {
        cartItemsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        placeYourOrderAdapter = new PlaceYourOrderAdapter(typeModel.getMenus());
        cartItemsRecyclerView.setAdapter(placeYourOrderAdapter);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

        if(requestCode == 1000) {
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
            finish();
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
        }//do nothing
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
        finish();
    }
}
```

orderfadapter

```
public class PlaceYourOrderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlaceYourOrderAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Menu> menuList;

    public PlaceYourOrderAdapter(List<Menu> menuList) {
        this.menuList = menuList;
    }

    public void updateData(List<Menu> menuList) {
        this.menuList = menuList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PlaceYourOrderAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view  = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.place_order_recycler_row, parent, false);
        return  new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PlaceYourOrderAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.menuName.setText(menuList.get(position).getName());
        holder.menuPrice.setText("Harga: Rp."+String.format("%.2f", menuList.get(position).getPrice()*menuList.get(position).getTotalInCart()));
        holder.menuQty.setText("Qty: " + menuList.get(position).getTotalInCart());
        Glide.with(holder.thumbImage)
                .load(menuList.get(position).getUrl())
                .into(holder.thumbImage);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return menuList.size();
    }

    static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView menuName;
        TextView  menuPrice;
        TextView  menuQty;
        ImageView thumbImage;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            menuName = view.findViewById(R.id.menuName);
            menuPrice = view.findViewById(R.id.menuPrice);
            menuQty = view.findViewById(R.id.menuQty);
            thumbImage = view.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
        }
    }
}
```

so the qty value is basically original read value subtracted by the amount of item being chosen, not sure if there is anyway to change the qty value without changing the menu.JSON file however any lead that been found around is a way to change specific line of a single line only and it must be chosen specifically

NB: I am dumb at this but at least i understand what the code do when i see it in action

i haven't really try anything because iam pretty oblivious because i don't understand what i should pass along to make the stuff possible however modifying and adding stuff is different story since i expect everyone can do that after understanding the code, what i expect is
[what being chosen orderf.activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFTty.png)
[what must change menu.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKdRl.png) or
[what must actually change on app menu.activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU3ax.png)
since after reading some other post i see that stream only read the json file once

Answer (score 0):

To update the qty value in the Menu object, you can modify the updateData method in PlaceYourOrderAdapter to accept a HashMap that maps the index of the Menu object to its new qty value. Then, you can update the Menu object at the specified index with the new qty value and notify the adapter of the data change using notifyItemChanged.

```
public void updateData(HashMap<Integer, Integer> updatedQuantities) {
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : updatedQuantities.entrySet()) {
        int index = entry.getKey();
        int newQty = entry.getValue();
        Menu menu = menuList.get(index);
        menu.setTotalInCart(newQty);
        notifyItemChanged(index);
    }
}
```

Then, in your PlaceYourOrderActivity, you can pass the updated qty values to the adapter by calling updateData on the adapter instance.

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> updatedQuantities = new HashMap<>();
// Populate the updatedQuantities map with the index and new qty value for each updated menu item
placeYourOrderAdapter.updateData(updatedQuantities);
```

This code assumes that you have access to the PlaceYourOrderAdapter instance in your PlaceYourOrderActivity. If you don't, you'll need to make the adapter instance a class variable and initialize it in your activity's onCreate method.

Comment: The much higher answer rate and the verboseness suggest this has been generated by [ChatGPT_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned).

Comment: it work fine without any error but not a single thing have changed afterward